# How to convert dp values to x and y float values for Corner radius?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I'm creating dashed rectangle with 12 dp corner radius.

I'm using canvas for that. In that we can't give corner radius in dp or px.

```
  Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            drawRoundRect(color = Color.Red, style = stroke, cornerRadius = CornerRadius(35f, 35f))
        }
```

In that I put 35f because it resembles 12 dp.
Is there any way to use dp or is there any way to covert dp/px to float xy values?

Comment: Did you try `12.dp.toPx()` ?

Comment: yes. it's working

Answer (score 4):

The `Canvas` works with a [`DrawScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope) which provides a [`Density`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density) interface.
With it you can use the [**`Dp.toPx()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density#(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp).toPx()) function:

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val px = 12.dp.toPx()
    drawRoundRect(color = Color.Red,style = stroke, cornerRadius = CornerRadius(px))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I didn't see this was a Compose question. That's noice

Answer (score 1):

*dp* is a "general size on the screen" value. The actual number of pixels that is depends on the device's screen density - a higher-density screen crams a lot more pixels into a given space, so a given *dp* value will translate into a higher *px* value

You can get that density factor from `Resources`:

```
context.resources.displayMetrics.density
```

and that value will give you your *dp-to-px* scaler. (You need that because `35f` will look very different on a hdpi screen compared to an xxxhdpi one)

Once you have your *px* value, you can just use it. You'll have a float after you multiply by `density` but you can just call `toInt` if you need to (or `toFloat` if you're going the other way). They're just different ways of expressing a value - what's important is that value is correct, that it represents the right number of pixels etc, whether it's `100` or `100f`